# django-import-export импорт xlsx

Tags: django

Пытаюсь импортировать большой объём данных (порядка 100000 строк) из .xlsx. Сервер сваливается в ошибку 500 при этом долго крутит и думает. Импорт малых данных проходит без проблем.

База: mysql внешнняя, доступ к базе по локалке
Плагин: django-import-export

Подскажите как можно организовать очередь или что типа чтобы импортировать такой большой объём.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, отваливается `nginx`/`gunicorn` по тайм-ауту (или какая там у вас связка). Можно подкрутить тайм-аут у самого сервере (воркера), но это максимально костыльное и бредовое решение.

Зачастую берут какую-то асинхронную либу (`celery`, `dramatiq` etc) и туда выносят такие задачи.

Главная суть в том, что всё это должно работать в другом, фоновом процессе.

Comment: Как с помощью celery можно организовать заполнение базы? Может ссылкой поделитесь где почитать!

Comment: https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/#celery-tasks